# CakePHP 3.x: query for related posts

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have `Posts` and `Tags` models, related with a "belongs to many" association.

So in my database I have `posts` and `tags` tables and a `posts_tags` table with `post_id` and `tag_id` fields. The `tags` table has the `post_count` field, showing the number of posts that belong to that tag.

When I get a post I get also tags related to it.

```
$this->Posts->find()
    ->contain(['Tags'])
    ->where(['Posts.id' => $id])
    ->first());
```

Now, for each tag, I would like to get a post that has that tag, excluding the initial post, sorted creation date (`created` field).
The important thing is that for each tag is getted a post other than those already getted.

I could use a `foreach` and for each tag get a post that contains it, by excluding the id of the initial post and those already getted.

I want to know if I can do this with a single query and have an example to work from.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**
**Temporary solution, which uses a query for each tag**

First, I get the main post:

```
$post = $this->Posts->find()
    ->contain(['Tags'])
    ->where(['Posts.id' => $id])
    ->first();
```

In this case the post is recovered through its ID, but you can do differently. Also you can use the cache.
The **important thing** is the `$post` variable.

Now (here is a good idea to use the cache...):

```
//Tries to gets related posts from cache
$related = Cache::read($cache = sprintf('related_posts_for_%s', $post->id), 'posts');

if(empty($related)) {
    $tags = $post->tags;

    //Re-orders tags, using the "post_count" field, then based on the popularity of tags
    usort($tags, function($a, $b) { return $b['post_count'] - $a['post_count']; });

    //Gets only the first 5 tags
    $tags = array_slice($tags, 0 , 5);

    //This array will be contain the ID to be excluded
    $exclude = [$post->id];

    //Gets a related post for each tag
    //Reveres the tags order, because the tags less popular have less chance to find a related post
    foreach(array_reverse($tags) as $tag) {
        $post = $this->Posts->find('active')
            ->select(['id', 'title', 'slug'])
            ->matching('Tags', function($q) use($tag) {
                return $q->where(['Tags.id' => $tag->id]);
            })
            ->where(['Posts.id NOT IN' => $exclude])
            ->first();

        //Adds the post to the related posts and its ID to the IDs to be excluded for the next query
        if(!empty($post)) {
            $related[] = $post;
            $exclude[] = $post->id;
        }
    }

    Cache::write($cache, $related, 'posts');
}

//Related posts
debug($related);
```

**NOTE: after this code, the `$post` variable no longer contains the original post. Pay attention or use a different variable name for related posts.**

Answer (score 1):

try this (not tested)

```
$this->Posts->find()
->contain([
    'Tags',
    'Tags.Posts' => function($q) use($id) {
        $q->where(['id !=' => $id])
            ->order(['created' => 'desc'])
            ->limit(1);
        return $q;
     }
   ])
->where(['Posts.id' => $id])
->first());
```

But in this way you'll may get a Post two times (and I see now that you don't want this)

Comment: thanks @arilia. But I want to separate these two queries. I guess it's the same thing, but using `matching()`. Is it right? But in this case there is a problem: this code may take twice the same post?

Comment: I don't understand: you said in the OP you want just one query and now you want two.

Comment: Suppose my post has `a` and `b` tags. Another post has the same tags. The same article (the second) will be getted twice, for each tag?

Comment: I'm trying your code. It seems there's a problem with the `limit()`, it always gets only a record

Comment: It should get a Post for every tag. The newest Post which is not the original Post (or more likely the oldest, I guess, as long I odered by created asc) . And yes: if a Post has a and b tags you'll get it twice, unless there's another older Post that has b tag

Comment: I edited the sort condition in order to get the newest post

Comment: Yes, but it seems it gets only a post for all tags,  not a post for each tags. I will try again, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: ok, I tested my code today and it did not worked as I believed it would. I'll think about another solution

Comment: If you see, you can't even use `select()`, in all case it retrieves all fields for the subquery. It seems strange to me

Comment: yes, select applies only to the main query. If you want to select the fields of the subquery you have to add a select statement in the contained query: `$q->select([...])`

Comment: Yes, using the `select()` statement in the cointained query has no effects

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to implement something described in [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) article. Probably it's possible to do in one query but maybe it's simpler if you make a query for every tag. At first I though that cake3 would do a foreach rather than make a inner join (cake 2 used to do this way). So my code was just an attempt to let cake make the loop for you. But since cake3 make an actual join this no longer works

Comment: Thanks @arilia. I have modified the initial post adding my code (a query for each tag). Tell me what you think...